# Location based AR with Vuforia unity3d plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality, location-based

I successfully integrated Vuforia plugin in unity3d, I set `World Center Mode` of Vuforia `AR Camera` object in scene to `DEVICE_TRACKING` to apply handheld device rotation to `AR Camera` object, it works fine and when I look around by my android mobile phone the Vuforia `AR camera` move in the scene too.
I set my location markers (Point of Interests) in their location in unity scene where x = latitude and z = longitude and set `AR Camera` `transform.position` to `Input.location.lastData` on each frame so when user move in real world the `AR Camera` also moves in unity scene, so far everything is OK!
the problem is here : **How set x and z axis of unity scene to real world North and East axis ?**
each time I run the app the my markers have different position in real world!
I think Vuforia `AR camera` assume initial angle of the camera as North.
[image: Point1 AR Marker]
in image you see Point1 AR Marker which remain at same point when I rotate device camera, but I want it to be at north , each time I run the app it is at my forward not on real world North axis
I use Unity 5.6.1f1 and Vuforia 6.2.6.

**Edit:**
How can I set unity Z axis point to real world North and unity X axis points to real world East?
[image: unity axis vs real world coordinate]

Comment: What phone are you using? What os version?

Comment: I'm using Android 6.0

Comment: Does your phone have a compass or gyroscope?

Comment: yes, I can see their variables by Input.compass and Input.gyro after enabling them